# How to find static version of zlib in CMake?

Tags: cmake, zlib

I'm on cmake version 3.12.1 and want to build a static executable that uses ZLIB. I have both the static (libz.a) and shared (libz.so) libraries on my machine. How can I tell `find_package(ZLIB)` to return the static version? Maybe there's another way to find `libz.a` as well?

My present workaround is to specify:

`SET(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} -static")`

Then:

`target_link_libraries (my_binary z lib1 lib2)`

Critique on this approach is also welcome!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### For `cmake_minimum_required` < 3.24

Your approach is valid given the limitations of the CMake module called by `find_package(ZLIB)`, specifically `FindZLIB.cmake`. While other `FindXXX.cmake` modules have a special option for grabbing static libraries, the zlib module does not.

There are already a few questions on SO about this topic, but some are older than others, so there are a few options.

You can instead apply the `-static` flag on a more granular level (rather than editing the global `CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS` variable) by adding it to your `target_link_libraries` call. This way it will apply only to that target -- useful if you are building other non-static targets.

You could also tell CMake to search for static libraries explicitly by setting [`CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES.html). When `find_package` is called, CMake can search for libraries ending in `.a` using this:

```
SET(CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES ".a")
find_package(ZLIB REQUIRED)
```

Comment: I wish you could write a quick sample about using `-static` flag with the `target _link_libraries` call.

Comment: You can just add `-static` to the end of the `target_link_libraries` call I believe; any of these such flags will be passed to the linker, so be sure your linker supports `-static`.

Answer (score 7):

As of CMake 3.24, use: `set(ZLIB_USE_STATIC_LIBS "ON")`

[Source](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/66aa34e5291b8bdf77b2b5b0984e97f458aad741/Modules/FindZLIB.cmake#L58)

Comment: Better to set this as an `option()` so that users can easily override.

Answer (score 2):

If you have control over installing `zlib`, for example, you are installing dependencies in a Continuous Integration setup, I would recommend to just remove the zlib dynamic library.

[zlib](https://github.com/madler/zlib) doesn't have the option to build statically or dynamically, it automatically generates both versions. However `FindZlib.cmake` prioritizes the dynamic version.

I find the following approach to be better in case you don't have access to modify third parties repositories `CMakeLists.txt` that needs `zlib`:

```
if (CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID STREQUAL "MSVC")
  set(_compiler_is_msvc ON)
endif()
option(ZLIB_FORCE_STATIC "Remove the dynamic libraries after zlib install" ON)
mark_as_advanced(ZLIB_FORCE_STATIC)

set(OUTPUT_BUILD_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR} CACHE PATH "Base folder where builds and source folder will be installed: i.e. OUTPUT_BUILD_DIR/zlib")

if(_compiler_is_msvc)
  set(ZLIB_GIT_TAG cacf7f1d4e3d44d871b605da3b647f07d718623f) # Version 1.2.11
  message(STATUS "ZLIB_VERSION: ${ZLIB_GIT_TAG} : Version 1.2.11")
  set(ZLIB_BUILD_DIR ${OUTPUT_BUILD_DIR}/zlib-build)
  set(ZLIB_INSTALL_DIR ${OUTPUT_BUILD_DIR}/zlib)
  set(ZLIB_SRC_FOLDER_NAME zlib-src)
  set(ZLIB_SRC_DIR ${OUTPUT_BUILD_DIR}/${ZLIB_SRC_FOLDER_NAME})
  set(ZLIB_GIT_REPOSITORY "https://github.com/madler/zlib")

  ExternalProject_Add(ep_zlib
    GIT_REPOSITORY ${ZLIB_GIT_REPOSITORY}
    GIT_TAG ${ZLIB_GIT_TAG}
    # GIT_SHALLOW TRUE
    GIT_PROGRESS TRUE
    CMAKE_GENERATOR ${CMAKE_GENERATOR}
    SOURCE_DIR ${ZLIB_SRC_DIR}
    BINARY_DIR ${ZLIB_BUILD_DIR}
    CMAKE_ARGS
        -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER:FILEPATH=${CMAKE_C_COMPILER}
        -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:FILEPATH=${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER}
        -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=${SGEXT_CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}
        -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS:BOOL=OFF
        -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=${ZLIB_INSTALL_DIR}
    )

  if(ZLIB_FORCE_STATIC)
    ExternalProject_Add_Step(
      ep_zlib zlib_remove_dll
      COMMENT "Remove zlib.lib and zlib.dll, leaves only zlibstatic.lib"
      DEPENDEES install
      COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E remove -f ${ZLIB_INSTALL_DIR}/lib/zlib.lib ${ZLIB_INSTALL_DIR}/bin/zlib.dll
      )
  endif()

endif()
```

The last step removes the dynamic version, so the default FindZLIB will find the static library.

Answer (score 2):

The best solution I found was to name the library explicitly when calling CMake:

```cpp
cmake -DZLIB_LIBRARY=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.a /path/to/source
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe CMake should simply add (proper) support for this, so I've [filed issue 24987](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/24987) against their repository.

Answer (score -1):

I would not recommend the solution proposed by @phcerdan because in my case the installed shared library was colliding with an already installed version, so the only solution was to make sure it never gets installed in the first place. The key idea is to disable completely the targets installation using `SKIP_INSTALL_LIBRARIES`, and instead to "install" the static library manually. Nonetheless, my solution is quite similar:

```
EXTERNALPROJECT_ADD(zlib_external
     GIT_REPOSITORY    https://github.com/madler/zlib.git
     GIT_TAG           v1.2.11

     CMAKE_ARGS
          -DSKIP_INSTALL_FILES=ON  # Disable install of manual and pkgconfig files
          -DSKIP_INSTALL_LIBRARIES=ON  # Do not install libraries automatically. It will be handled manually to avoid installing shared libs
          -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF
          -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=${CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE}
          -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}
          -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS:STRING=${CMAKE_COMPILE_FLAGS_EXTERNAL}
          ${EXTERNALPROJECT_BUILD_TYPE_CMD}
     INSTALL_DIR ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}
)

if(NOT WIN32)
     set(zlib_BUILD_LIB_PATH "<BINARY_DIR>/libz.a")
     set(zlib_PATH "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib/libz.a")
else()
     set(zlib_BUILD_LIB_PATH "<BINARY_DIR>/Release/zlibstatic.lib")
     set(zlib_PATH "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib/zlibstatic.lib")
endif()

ExternalProject_Add_Step(
     zlib_external zlib_install_static_only
     COMMENT "Manually installing only static library"
     DEPENDEES install
     COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy ${zlib_BUILD_LIB_PATH} ${zlib_PATH}
)
```